# How to Center Asp MVC Table Objects?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I've got a list of objects based of the table view built into aspmvc and.. it looks like this.[image]

Problem is, I'd like all the elements to be aligned in the center. The code is pretty generic, literally the generated code I believe.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_EmailAddress)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_CellNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_CompanyName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_CompanyAddress)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_CompanyState)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_CompanyZip)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_CompanyPhone)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_CompanyWebsite)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_WorkTravelRange)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_CompanyCostCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.m_CompanyAccountType)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_EmailAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_CellNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_CompanyName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_CompanyAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_CompanyState)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_CompanyZip)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_CompanyPhone)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_CompanyWebsite)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_WorkTravelRange)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_CompanyCostCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.m_CompanyAccountType)
        </td>
        @*<td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.m_IdentityCode }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.m_IdentityCode }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.m_IdentityCode })
        </td>*@
```

My instincts tell me to..

```
<table class = "table" align = "center">
```

But to to avail.

Could some one point me in the right direction? Please and thank you.

Edit:

I tried `<th text-align: center>` but it still looks aligned left.

[image]

Comment: Style you `th` and `td` elements with `text-align: center`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, Sir.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated the question, looks to still be aligned left.

Comment: `<style>th,td { text-align: center; }</style>` (or if you were to do it in each element `<th style="text-align: center">`)

Comment: Yeah it seems to work as well, I just can't seem to get the text to center, like they're in the center of the column but relative to themselves they're left aligned I feel like.

Comment: Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asrah005/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sweet, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can apply the style to the entire table by just using

```
.table th, .table td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

you can include this in your page markup... so just before `<table>`

```
<style type="text/css">
    .table th, .table td {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<table class="table">
```

or you can put the code in a site css file that your layout or view is referencing

Comment: Trying it now :P So much simpler.

Comment: Uhh, I'm apparently retarded. Where should I put this?

Comment: @Eidenai that goes in your css page, then you have to reference your css page at the top of your view.  If you do not want every table to behave the same way you should give it it's own class though like centerAlignTable

Comment: Cool, thanks. :) Now I have like three ways to do it!

Answer (score 2):

Use `<th align="center">... </th>`

[source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now.

Comment: Derp, so like.. I don't know why I thought it didn't work, but thank you :) I'll select it as the answer when the timer is up.